# Any Rails-Migration-like framework suggestions for .NET?

Tags: database, migration

The idea of "rails migration" is awesome and I'm going to use this way in my coming new project on .NET platform for db schema version control.

[MigratorDotNet](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet) seems like something I need but some limitations block me, such as no stored procedure support. Are there any better solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar question, which incidentally shows up as one of the top google results (wooo, gogo stackoverflow!) with a nice roundup in the top scoring post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313/net-migrations-engine